# prototypes: Why does modifying "child" object instance also modifies "parent" object instance?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, data-structures, graph, prototype

I'm trying to write implement a graph (the data structure) in Javascript. To do so I have a function called `Graph` that stores this matrix in a 2D array in an attribute called `this.adjMatrix`. It also has a bunch of methods.

I also want to create something called a residual graph, which takes a `Graph` object, creates a copy of `this.adjMatrix` for itself, and modifies this copy, and saves it in it's own `this.adjMatrix` attribute.

Now, I want the residual graph to have access to all of `Graph`'s functions as well, so I made `Graph` a prototype of `ResidualGraph`. However, this brought about an issue. Here is a look at my implementation:

```
function ResidualGraph(G) {

    this.adjMatrix = G.adjMatrix.slice(); 
    this.idList = G.idList.slice();

    this.init = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < this.adjMatrix.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < this.adjMatrix[i].length; j++) {
                if (i != j && G.adjMatrix[i][j] != -Infinity && G.adjMatrix[i][j] != 0) {
                    this.adjMatrix[j][i] = 0;
                };
            };
        };
    };
    this.init();
};

ResidualGraph.prototype = new Graph();
G = new Graph();
R = new ResidualGraph();
```

When the `init()` method runs (on creation of an instance of `ResidualGraph`) the instance of `ResidualGraph` has its `this.adjMatrix` modified as desired. However, the instance of `Graph` that was passed in *also* has its `this.adjMatrix` modified for some reason. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the issue was not with the prototype! It was simply the fact that .slice() only creates a shallow copies. As a result, the `this.adjMatrix` in the `ResidualGraph` was the `this.adjMatrix`in `Graph`.